# Register loading when it shouldnt

Tags: vhdl

So, i've this register that has synchronous load (e_inter(4)) and reset signals:

```
--Register Rx2
process (clk)
begin
    if clk'event and clk = '1'then
        if reset = '1' then
            Rx2 <= X"00000000";
        elsif e_inter(4) = '1'then
            Rx2 <= mul1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Problem is that even if i allways set `e_inter(4) = '0'` all the time, the register still loads the value from `mul1` into `Rx2`. I can see that `e_inter(4) = '0'` in the simulation and that when the rising edge of clock comes it makes `Rx2 <= mul1` . Any thoughts?

Comment: Whatever the problem may be, it isn't in this snippet of code. Show us your testbench, the assignments of `mul1`, `reset`, `clk`, `e_inter`, and do a text search for "`Rx2`" to make sure you don't have a multiple driver problem.

Comment: Found out what the real problem was... I thought e_inter(4) = '0', but it didnt, i was reading the array as a C array instead of a VHDL array, so i was messing with e_inter(0) instead of e_inter(4)